# How to check Audio is finished or not in just audio library?

Tags: flutter

How to check audio is completed or not?

On finished change icon from pause to play.

Comment: What library are you using for playing audio? Please provide the code you are using

Answer (score 6):

there is a way to listen to state changes
you can use that

```dart
      audioPlayer.playerStateStream.listen((state) {
        if (state.processingState == ProcessingState.completed) {
          onComplete();
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

use audioplayers:
https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers

```
 player.onPlayerCompletion.listen((event) {
    onComplete();
    setState(() {
      position = duration;
    });
  });
```